# Dependency issues when executing gt-imagemosaic-jdbc-23.5.jar to import tiles into postgres db

Tags: geoserver, geotools, image-mosaic, maven, jdbc

After creating tiles, I'm trying to insert these tiles into postgres db which I had created earlier. Here's  the [procedure](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic-jdbc/imagemosaic-jdbc_tutorial.html). Now when trying to import these tiles to database, I have to execute this command:

```
java -jar <your_geoserver_install_dir>/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-imagemosaic-jdbc-{version}.jar import  -config <your geoserver data dir>/coverages/osm.postgis.xml -spatialTNPrefix tileosm -tileTNPrefix tileosm -dir tiles -ext png
```

The **problem** is that I'm getting these weird import errors:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.geotools.util.URLs
```

Even when I somehow find the package and install it, some other import error pops-up. Most of these packages are org.geotools
and I can't find most of them.

Is there a way to solve these dependencies issue?

Answer (score 1):

The image mosaic JDBC module was demoted to unsupported in April 2020 after years of neglect. The fact that the page you are following is for version **1.7** of GeoServer says a lot as we are currently preparing for version 2.20.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I was able to solve this by building [geotools](https://github.com/geotools/geotools) using maven. Then placed the necessary `.jar` files in JDK environment from where I was running the command mentioned in the question. So, I guess *imagemosaic-jdbc* is still usable in a way.